# systemd-networkd-wait-online lo issues

Tags: linux, networking, systemd

`systemd-networkd-wait-online` is failing and timing out on boot. I am running Ubuntu 22.04.3

I have three interfaces:

```
$ networkctl status -a
● 1: lo
                     Link File: n/a
                  Network File: n/a
                          Type: loopback
                         State: carrier (unmanaged)
                  Online state: unknown
                    HW Address: 00:00:00:00:00:00
                           MTU: 65536
                         QDisc: noqueue
  IPv6 Address Generation Mode: eui64
          Queue Length (Tx/Rx): 1/1
                       Address: 127.0.0.1
                                ::1
             Activation Policy: up
           Required For Online: yes

● 2: enp33s0
                     Link File: /usr/lib/systemd/network/99-default.link
                  Network File: /run/systemd/network/10-netplan-all.network
                          Type: ether
                         State: routable (configured)
                  Online state: unknown
                          Path: pci-0000:21:00.0
                        Driver: ixgbevf
                        Vendor: Intel Corporation
                         Model: X550 Virtual Function
                    HW Address: *
                           MTU: 1500 (min: 68, max: 9710)
                         QDisc: mq
  IPv6 Address Generation Mode: eui64
          Queue Length (Tx/Rx): 8/8
              Auto negotiation: no
                         Speed: 10Gbps
                        Duplex: full
                       Address: 10.20.31.45 (DHCP4 via 10.20.31.229)
                                *
                           DNS: 10.20.31.229
                Search Domains: *
             Activation Policy: up
           Required For Online: no
               DHCP4 Client ID: IAID:0xa8cc043a/DUID
             DHCP6 Client DUID: DUID-EN/Vendor:0000ab117136b3e83ccf80800000

● 3: enp27s0
                     Link File: /run/systemd/network/10-netplan-enp27s0.link
                  Network File: /run/systemd/network/10-netplan-all.network
                          Type: ether
                         State: routable (configured)
                  Online state: unknown
                          Path: pci-0000:1b:00.0
                        Driver: virtio_net
                        Vendor: Red Hat, Inc.
                         Model: Virtio network device
                    HW Address: *
                           MTU: 1500 (min: 68, max: 1500)
                         QDisc: fq_codel
  IPv6 Address Generation Mode: eui64
          Queue Length (Tx/Rx): 1/1
              Auto negotiation: no
                         Speed: n/a
                       Address: 10.145.101.139 (DHCP4 via 169.254.75.10)
                                *
                       Gateway: 169.254.1.1
                           DNS: 10.135.192.10
                Search Domains: *
             Activation Policy: up
           Required For Online: no
               DHCP4 Client ID: IAID:0x9d8432b/DUID
             DHCP6 Client DUID: DUID-EN/Vendor:0000ab117136b3e83ccf80800000
```

Below are outcomes for various tests once the system is booted

```bash
# "Timeout occurred while waiting for network connectivity."
/lib/systemd/systemd-networkd-wait-online --any
/lib/systemd/systemd-networkd-wait-online --interface=lo
/lib/systemd/systemd-networkd-wait-online --ignore=lo


# Works
/lib/systemd/systemd-networkd-wait-online --interface=enp27s0
/lib/systemd/systemd-networkd-wait-online --interface=enp33s0
/lib/systemd/systemd-networkd-wait-online --interface=enp33s0 --interface=enp27s0
```

Is this expected? Is there anything further I can do to troubleshoot the issue?